# Is $ f\left(x\right) =\int^{x}_{0}\sin( e^{t^{2}})\,\mathrm{d}t$ uniformly continuous?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Show that:

$$f\left(x\right) =\int^{x}_{0}\sin\left( e^{t^{2}}\right)d\,\mathrm{d}t$$

Is uniformly continuous

I have tried to integrate it and bound it by using its limits, but a little unsure about what to do from there.

Comment: I noticed you have yet to accept any answers to your questions here. You can increase your reputation (and also gain more privileges on this website) by accepting answers. You can do this by clicking the check mark underneath the downvote arrow on the answer you would like to accept.

Comment: You can only accept one answer per question. But it did work as you can see the green check mark underneath Micapps' answer.

Comment: $|f(x)-f(y)|=\Bigl|\int_x^y \sin (e^{t^2})\,dx \Bigr|\le\Bigl|\int_x^y 1\,dx \Bigr|\le|x-y|$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the derivative is bounded then it is uniformly continuous, can you see how that would apply here?

We have that the $\sin$ function is bounded by $1$, i.e. $|\sin(x)| \leq 1$. Using the fundamental theorem of calculus we obtain that $f'(x)=\sin(e^{x^2})$, and applying our knowledge of $\sin(x)$ we get $|\sin(e^{x^2})|\leq 1$. By the mean value theorem we get that

$|\sin(e^{x^2})-\sin(e^{y^2})|\leq (1)|x-y|$. Hence our function is uniformly continuous since for any $\epsilon>0$ we only need to choose $\delta<\epsilon$.

Comment: @Tom Otto edited for clarification

Answer (score 3):

Note that $f$ is differentiable, with derivative $f'(x)=\sin (e^{x^2})$. Thus $|f'(x)|\le 1$. So $f$ has bounded variation and is therefore uniformly continuous.